WeakRef and garbage collection don't work as expected
In my project I found myself in need of using WeakRefs and FinalizationRegistry, but I can't quite manage to make it work, so I created a simple example and it also does not work. Can you help me figure out why the simple example does not work:
Example code:
    let ref = new WeakRef({});

    console.log("log", ref, ref.deref());

    global.gc();

    new Promise((res)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{res()}, 100_000)
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log("log2", ref, ref.deref());
    })

    global.gc();

    console.log("log3", ref, ref.deref());

expected output:
log WeakRef {} {}

log3 WeakRef {} undefined // maybe here still log3 WeakRef {} {}

log2 WeakRef {} undefined // here for sure!!!

Real output:
log WeakRef {} {}

log3 WeakRef {} {}

log2 WeakRef {} {}

alternative without "forcing" garbage collection with global.gc() also yielded the result above.
command I used to run examples:
node --expose-gc {filename}.js in case of the code above or
node {filename}.js when running tests without global.gc()
node versions I tried:
17.9.1
20.10.0
21.7.3

Garbage collection cannot happen during synchronous execution of code in which the value of the WeakRef was observed. That is, when you construct a new WeakRef(o) or get an object from o = weakRef.deref(), then until your code runs to completion weakRef.deref() will always return o. A garbage collection cycle occurring (or being triggered using global.gc()) in between cannot collect the object.
So you need to delay the call a bit, putting it in your setTimeout:
let ref = new WeakRef({});
// even when a garbage collection happens (by chance) here
console.log("log", ref, ref.deref()); // this will always return the object

setTimeout(() => {
    global.gc(); // now it will be collected
    console.log("log2", ref, ref.deref());
}, 100);

